# I want to modify the LCR algorithm so I can have more than one leader

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to modify the algorithm but something doesn't work very good and because I am new to JavaScript/server/client problems, I cannot understand the problem.

First of all should I modify the server and the client files or just the client? Here is the part of the client file I modify. And can you explain me how I should enter my code?

```
//nodeID = the id of the node in the circle
//inID = is the incomming id from the left node
//k=is the number of the leaders i want
//flag = checking if all leader have been elected
function processRound(message, round) {
    if (round == 0) {
        addToMessage("ID", nodeId);
    } 
    else {
        if (flag == 0) {
            if (inId > nodeId) {
                addToMessage("ID", inId);
            } 
            else if (inId == nodeId) {
                leader = true;
                addLog("I am the leader");
            } 
            else if (inId < nodeId) {
            }
        } 
        else if (flag == 1) {
            if (inId == nodeId) {
            } 
            else {
                if (k < 0) {
                    leader = true;
                    k = k - 1;
                } 
                else if (k > 0) {
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Proper indentation makes your code more readable. Blank lines between (nearly) every statement makes it less readable.

Comment: *"something doesn't work very good"* And what exactly? And what does "not very good" mean in this context? What do you expect to happen and what does happen? If you are not properly explaining the issue you are experiencing, then we cannot really help you.

Comment: i need to modify the LCR algorithm so it can elect k leader and not only one ,but when i run it it just stops and doesnt elect any leader

Comment: i use blank line because i had  problems on how to write the code sorry next time it wont have blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me help you a bit. K=3.You should  implement lcr algorithm 3 times excluding the found leaders.